# Processing.js array of pictures not showing properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, processing.js

I am trying to take picture path data from my database and show it on the processing sketch like so this is Javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function send() {
            function  setPath(d) {
                var s = d;
                var processingInstance;
                if (!processingInstance) {
                    processingInstance = Processing.getInstanceById('canvas');
                }
                processingInstance.change(s);
            }
            var variable = 2;
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                tupe: "POST",
                url: "take.php",
                data: ({val: variable}),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#msg').html(data);
                    setPath(data);
                },
            });
        }</script>
```

this is PHP file:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'Admin', 'xkmpfg3t', 'test');

if (!$con) {
   echo mysqli_errno($con);
}

if ($_POST) {
    $temp = $_POST['val'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT* FROM `pictures` WHERE `user_id` = $temp");
    if (!$query) {
        mysqli_errno($con);
    }
    $im = array();
    $i = 0;
    $img;
    while ($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $img = $image['picture_name'];
        $im[$i] = "$img";
        $i += 1;
    }
    foreach ($im as $i => $value) {
        echo " $value";
    }
  // echo $im;
}
?>
```

and this is my Processing.js code here:

```
String pic ;
PImage img;
int x;
int y;
int pad = 10;
int bs = 50;
String[] list = new String[0];

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  background(150);
  //img = loadImage(pic);
}

void draw(){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length ; i++){ 
        x = pad + (bs+pad)*i;
        y = pad;
        image(img,x,y,bs,bs);
    }

}

void change(String val){
    list = split(val," ");
    for(int i = 0; i <list.length; i++){    
        pic = list[i];
        img = loadImage(pic);
        println(pic);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the sketch, it shows me one image more and only the last element of the array. If I have 5 elements, in the skatch area, I have 6 same images with the fifth element of the array. How can I fix this and to see 5 different images instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it this way: you only have one `img` variable, so you're only ever showing a single image!

Take a closer look at your loop:

```
 for(int i = 0; i <list.length; i++){    
        pic = list[i];
        img = loadImage(pic);
        println(pic);
    }
```

You're looping through `list` and getting the images from it, but you're just constantly setting the `img`  variable over and over again. At the end of this loop, `img` will just equal the last image in the list.

Instead of using a single `img` variable, you probably want to use an array or an `ArrayList`. Here's a basic start:

```
PImage[] images;

void draw(){
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length ; i++){ 
        x = pad + (bs+pad)*i;
        y = pad;
        image(images[i],x,y,bs,bs);
    }
}

void change(String val){
    list = split(val," ");
    images = new PImage[list.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){    
        images[i] = loadImage(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tryed but the for loop in the draw is never executed and i get strange error in the debugger it says `Type of error: image is null`.

Comment: @MimiChan Please create a new question with an updated [mcve]. Please include the exact error message, as well as which line the error is on. Also include the image files you're loading. They should be hard-coded instead of passed in from PHP.