# Browser crash after running processing sketch

Tags: processing.js

When i receive data from server and try to show it on the skreen my browser crash and the ram is full how can i fix this. This is my code:

```
String pic ;
PImage img;
int x;
int y;
int pad = 10;
int bs = 50;
String[] list = new String[0];

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  background(150);
  //img = loadImage(pic);
}

void draw(){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length ; i++){ 
        x = pad + (bs+pad)*i;
        y = pad;
        pic = list[i];
        img = loadImage(pic);
        image(img,x,y,bs,bs);
        println(pic);
    }
}
void change(String val){
    list = split(val," ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `loadImage()` from the `draw()` function.

The `draw()` function is called 60 times every second, and you're loading an entire list, so you're loading hundreds of images every second. Your browser can't handle that.

Think about it this way: you should only load each image **once**. Reloading it 60 times per second is extreme overkill.

Instead, do the loading from the `change()` function, which I've explained how to do in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562911/processing-js-array-of-pictures-not-showing-propperly).