# Processing.js canvas not show the array of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, canvas, processing.js

I recive the Ajax data from the server which contain string with the location on the disk of the images when i loop it i get all the images and store them in the array and i can retrieve them after that. But when i try to show them in the canvas nothing is hapened i asume it is because the browser can not load the images so quicly but i am not shore, if someone know how to solve this problem pls tell me. Here is the code of my sketch:

```
PImage img;
int x;
int y;
int pad = 10;
int bs = 50;
String[] Pictures = [];

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  background(150);
  frameRate(1);
  //img = loadImage(pic);
}

void draw(){
    for (int i = 0; i < Pictures.length ; i++){ 
    String pic; 
        pic = Pictures[i];
        img = loadImage(pic);
        //println (pic);
        x = pad + (bs+pad)*i;
        y = pad;
        image(img,x,y,bs,bs);
        println(i);
        println(Pictures[i]);
    }

}

void change(String val){
String[]  list = split(val," ");
    for(int i = 0; i <list.length; i++){
        Pictures[i] = list[i];
        pic = Pictures[i];
        //println("Picture: "+Pictures[i]);
        //println("List: "+list[i]); 
        //println(list[i]);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing.js array of pictures not showing propperly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562911/processing-js-array-of-pictures-not-showing-propperly)

Comment: Please don't post multiple copies of the same question. Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562911/processing-js-array-of-pictures-not-showing-propperly/39619880#39619880